# Optimisation of a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, system-performance

I've opened a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179953/iterative-loop-for-a-given-list), which was answered. The code works totally fine for a small set of data. However, for a large set and over many iterations, it will take a long time (in order of 24 hours). Here I am going to provide a realistic example and the implementation of the code,

```
ELCo = Alphabet["English"];
Characters[ToLowerCase[WordList[Language -> "English"]]];
Select[%, SubsetQ[ELCo, ToLowerCase[#1]] &];
GPr = Map[Sort, Map[DeleteDuplicates, %]];
```

This code makes a list off all english words and separates them by letters and gets rid of duplicated characters. This list is called `GPr` and is all we need for the rest of the procedure. Now what I want is to find the commonest set of 2 and relabel it. For instance if `{"a","b"}` is the most common I replace it with `"AB"`, indeed the following code goes through the list `GPr` and for each word, when there is a `{"a","b"}`combination, it does the relabelling:

```
ClearAll[replace]
replace = 
  With[{commonest = 
      Commonest[Flatten[Map[Subsets[#, {2}] &, #], 1]][[
       1]]}, # //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[## & @@ commonest, 
        p___]} :> {StringJoin[ToUpperCase[commonest]], p}] &;
```

Next would be the result using:

```
n = 200;
x = Table[Nest[replace, GPr, i], {i, n}];
```

n is the number of time I want this procedure to be done. Basically every time it shall look at the previous list, take the most common pair and does the replacement. How shall I optimise the code to be able to run it for n=200 in a short period of time. Note that `GPr` has 39980 elements and it is large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) instead of [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) & [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html), you can improve the speed from $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ to $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{f(n)})$.

On my laptop, this improves the runtime from ~30s to ~2.5s for $n=20$ and the first 1000 elements of `GPr`. (The estimated runtime for the full problem is around 10min):

```
n = 20;
x = NestList[replace, GPr[[;; 1000]], n] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.44462, …} *)
x2 = Table[Nest[replace, GPr[[;; 1000]], n], {i, n}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {29.7638, …} *)
```

The reason is simply that you don't need to recompute the first $i-1$ steps for the $i$<sup>th</sup> step.